# In new game plus, can you get summoned to an "auto summon" area

Tags: dark-souls-3

In new game plus, if wearing auto summon covenants like darkmoon, aldrich, farron, etc are you able to get summoned to those zones prior to visiting them in the new game cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are eligible for summons.

Right in my NG++ I haven't even reached Abyss Watchers, but I was summoned as Blade of Darkmoon into Grand Archives.

Comment: thanks! You're lucky... I ***still*** have not been summoned a single time under darkmoon and I'm in my second cycle :(

Comment: I've put in about 100 hours across 3 names and I'm yet to be summoned once as a blade of the darkmoon